# How to get a running sum - floating above the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column of natural numbers (1, 2, 3...) and I want to know the sum up until a certain point **without opening a new column that would calculate the sum**.

Basically, I want to have a floating label, that pops whenever I hover on a cell, with a formula in it - where the formula is `sum(A1:A<current_index>)`

Is that possible? (I'm also fine with the having that data pop on the column's header instead)

*I'm working in google sheets, so some of MSExcel functions won't be available I guess*

Comment: In Excel, if you select a bunch of cells, there will be info one them in the lower right of the window; don't know if that also happens in google sheets.

Comment: It does, but I really want the pop up feature

Comment: Are you willing to code in google app script to implement such a function? I am not sure even how, but in VBA you could add code to the selection change event and add/remove comments with the selected  totals as text.

Comment: Willing, but hoped it would be something generic for all excel like apps

Answer (score 2):

Doing exactly want you want isn't really possible unless you use macros in VBA for Excel, or maybe Google App Script in Sheets.

An interesting way to *almost* do this without macros only requires you to hit F9 / recalculate in order to update the total:

1. Insert a floating textbox shape next to the column header. Set the textbox properties to "Allow text to overflow shape" and uncheck "Wrap text in shape".
2. With the shape selected, click in the formula bar and input say `=P1`.
3. Make the shape as invisible as possible, i.e. minimal size, no fill, no borders
4. In cell P1 enter the following formula

> ```
> =LET(selected, CELL("address"), selectedcol, MID(selected, 2, FIND("$",selected, 2)-2), selectedrow, MID(selected, FIND("$",selected,2)+1,10),IF(AND(selectedcol="A",--selectedrow>1,--selectedrow<20),SUM($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,selectedrow)),""))
> ```

5. The formula in P1 (and thus the textbox) will only update if you edit any cell (which forces a recalculate), hit Formulas > Calculate Now, or press F9 (shortcut key).
6. If you are in range (e.g. column A2 to A19) then the textbox will show the total otherwise show blank.

[image]

*Ps. This unfortunately only works in Excel. Google Sheets does not have a standard function to return the currently selected cell. Also, if you don't have the LET function, you can simply substitute each LET name into the primary formula.*

Comment: Hi @Mobus for better understanding please [edit] the post & add some screen shot , will help me and others too,,, to realize the method behind !!

Comment: @RajeshSinha I have added the screenshot as requested.

Comment: ,,, nice one you get +10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

In Excel to display floating message/Label, literally you need VBA macro. Instead of a Label better think for Message Box, will appear while selecting the cell, also display the formula in that particular cell.

**Caveat**

*The shown VBA code will work with any version of EXCEL only,, never with Google sheet. Readers before getting judgmental please check the TAG with question.*

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Either select the Sheet TAB & **R**ight Click the mouse and from pop up
   menu select **V**iew Code or press **Alt+F11**,, you get VB editor window.
2. **C**opy & **P**aste this code as Standard module.

   ```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Q2:Q6")) Is Nothing Then _
       MsgBox "You have select cell " & Target.Address & " , Formula in cell is " & Target.Formula & vbCrLf, vbInformation, "Formula in Current cell"

    End Sub
   ```
3. Now press **Alt+Q**.
4. Save the workbook as Macro Enable `*.xlsm`.
5. Select the cell, you get the message box along with formula.

**N.B.**

*Remember `(Target, Range("Q2:Q6"))`, the range `Q2:Q6` is adjustable.*

Comment: Nice VBA solution! Adding the message to a cell comment/note may be better than a message box which could be quite intrusive. E.g. `Sheet1.Range("A1").AddComment (Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("A2:A19"))`

Comment: @Mobus  , thanks for responding the post,, yes it would be good option,,, ☺